# is there a Unicode character for Copy and Paste?

Tags: unicode

Are there Unicode characters that represent Copy and Paste? Perhaps in Unicode 6?

(there are scissor symbols that can be used fittingly to represent Cut (e.g. ✂ U+2702) but i could never find one to represent Copy or Paste.)

Comment: Note: there's undo ⎌ (U+238C; UNDO SYMBOL) but i havn't found Redo. Here's Unicode symbols related to computing i've collected so far  http://xahlee.org/comp/unicode_computing_symbols.html

Comment: i just found this one 

Comment: @StrangerintheQ For me (in Firefox 112) that's just a rectangle with 01F5D0 written inside it over two lines. That means it isn't that good if it isn't widely supported.

Answer (score 32):

How about this: `&#x2398;` = ⎘ which looks kind of like a *copy from clipboard*.

Comment: that's a good one, but though that char's name is NEXT PAGE, which means relying on a particular font's rendering to represent clipboard will be unreliable. I'm thinking Unicode 6 must have it... haven't found it there yet.

Comment: @Xeoncross this is incomplete. Maybe you forgot a `;` (semicolon) after the hex entity.

Comment: @SK-the-Learner I edited that semicolon in, just have to wait for the edit to get approved.

Answer (score 25):

My solution is to use two  emojis and layer them over each other like so:

```html
<span style="font-size: .875em; margin-right: .125em; position: relative; top: -.25em; left: -.125em">
  <span style="position: absolute; top: .25em; left: .25em"></span>
</span>
```

(Of course I'm a web developer, so I have access to HTML.  You might need to accomplish this another way.  But I'm guessing a good chunk of people looking for an answer to this UI problem are using unicode in a website.)

The neat thing about this solution is if the thing you're copying is better represented by an icon other than , you might be able to switch out the emoji for something else.

The scissor ✂️ and clipboard  emojis are then suitable cut/paste companions.

Answer (score 23):

For Paste, the CLIPBOARD symbol (U+1F4CB) would be likely;

Comment: Can't argue with this one:  (u+1f4cb) like your answer states.

Answer (score 20):

I use [scissors](https://unicode-table.com/en/2702/) character for “cut out” on site — https://unicode-table.com/

To copy I use [two squares](https://unicode-table.com/en/29C9/) but you could also use — [Two Consecutive Equals Signs](https://unicode-table.com/en/2A75/) or [Mahjong Tile Two of Bamboos](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F011/).

To paste I use - [Clipboard characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F4CB/).
These characters correspond to characters in word.

Answer (score 7):

Was looking as well, found these alternatives: ☍ ⊕ ⎘ ⩲ ⨧ ⑃   ended up using ⎘ like suggested above

Answer (score 4):

There is an insertion symbol: `x2380` ⎀

Answer (score 3):

## An (HTML-only) solution using emojis from the modern set<sup>*</sup>

| Concept | HTML character code | Literal Emoji |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Copy = Camera | `&#128247;` |  |
| Cut = Scissors | `&#9986;&#65039;` | ✂️ |
| Paste = Clipboard | `&#128203;` |  |

- Emojis vary in appearance depending on device and font in use

Answer (score 1):

To summarize some great findings here with updated links:

Copy: , [⎘](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2398/index.htm)

Paste:

Cut: [✂](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2702/index.htm)(✂️), [✄](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2704/index.htm), [✀](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2700/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode encodes characters used in texts, not ideas or concepts. So unless there is a character commonly used in texts to symbolize cut and paste, you shouldn’t expect to find such a symbol in Unicode.

U+2702 BLACK SCISSORS is in Unicode since it appears in older character codes, and it has been used in printed documents to indicate a cutting line, as a “cut here” indicator, rather than as a symbol of copying.

Comment: copy and paste icon are used quick often i think, more often than quite a lot symbols that are included in unicode. See this page for example http://xahlee.org/comp/unicode_dingbats.html

Comment: @Xah Just because unicode has some wacky symbols, doesn't mean it should be wacky-complete. The existing symbols are a compromise, and getting more would be a never-ending quest.

Comment: @Tobu, i don't think this line of thought is correct description of Unicode. Unicode 6 added thousands of symbols, much of it are emoticons, traffic signs, icon of cars, trains, boats ... etc. Here's a list of emoticons http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-6.0/U60-1F600.pdf

Comment: @Xah Lee, the new characters have existing usage in texts, though in specialized contexts (like Japanese text messaging). We could expect to find a “copy and paste” character in Unicode only if there were an actual character with established usage and some identity. I have never seen such a symbol, though I know the *idea* of copy and paste. There are symbols used for “copy” and “paste” separately, but even they haven’t been encoded as characters.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela there's many existing use for copy/paste sign. Most are kinda standardize looking like pasteboard. In most apps that have a tool bar. emacs, MS Word, email apps ..., and often in web sites too.

Comment: (1) Unicode isn't minimal; encoding ubiquitous UI symbols helps create portable applications. (2) Unicode encodes symbols, not just characters; like the UNDO SYMBOL, mentioned by OP.

Comment: "not ideas or concepts" - I think this conceptualization might need to be revised in the 2020s, given the plethora of emoji and glyphs that have been added. Unicode Explained pt 2 perhaps? :)