# How to insert icons inside text in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React Component which contains a description text.
The entire description (the link and the plain text) comes in one string variable:
[image]
Sometimes the description can contain more than one link.
I need to add a "Copy" Icon and a "Open in new tab" Icon at the end of the link (where the red arrow points).

Comment: Use a library called react-icons

Comment: You can use the icon within text and it would show up without disrupting the flow of it. You can insert it inside any text-specific element such as `<p>` or `<b>` and it should show up alongside the text normally.

Comment: Is there any predefined structure to this string?  You'll have to parse and transform it somehow.

Comment: @zero298 no there isn't, I just know that it may contain some links randomly anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I think you need break the url become another text, like this:

```js
function splitText(text) {
    const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/;
    const urlMatch = text.match(urlRegex);
    let result = {
        'textBeforeUrl': text,
        'url':'',
        'textAfterUrl':''
    }
  
    if (!urlMatch) {
        return result
    }
  
    const url = urlMatch[0];
    const index = text.indexOf(url);
    const textBeforeUrl = text.substring(0, index);
    const textAfterUrl = text.substring(index + url.length);
    result.textBeforeUrl = textBeforeUrl;
    result.url = url;
    result.textAfterUrl = textAfterUrl;
    return result
}
```

After that, create a component

```js
const textResult = splitText(text)
<span>
 <p>{textResult.textBeforeUrl}</p>
 <p>{textResult.url}</p><Icon/>
 <p>{textResult.textAfterUrl}</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to identify the URL using regular expression to match URLs as follow :

```
const description = "YOUR_DESCRIPTION_HERE"
const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
const segments = description.split(urlRegex);
```

Then map your description and handle rendering based on the regex rule:

```
<div>
  {segments.map((segment, index) => {
    if (segment.match(urlRegex)) {
      // THIS IS LINK ->
      return (
        <span key={index}>
          {segment}
          <button onClick={() => handleCopy(segment)}>Copy</button>
          <a href={segment} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Open in new tab</a>
        </span>
      );
    } else {
      // THIS IS PLAIN TEXT ->
      return <span key={index}>{segment}</span>;
    }
  })}
</div>
```

and this is the function to handle copy action:

```
const handleCopy = (link) => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(link)
    .then(() => console.log('Link copied to clipboard'))
    .catch((error) => console.error('Failed to copy link:', error));
};
```

In general that should give you the desired feature, Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: I don't think they are seeking the implementation for this, I think they just needed text glyphs, which is why this question should either be closed as duplicate or unclear, unless clarification is provided by the OP. If this is truly what the OP seeks, then it should be one of the many duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score -1):

Use an icon library like `react-icons`, for example.

Install: `npm i react-icons`

Then import the icon in your React component:

```
import { FaCopy } from "react-icons/fa";
```

Use it within the JSX:

```
<p>
  <FaCopy /> TEXT BESIDES THE ICON
</p>
```

It contains icons from multiple popular sources, including material design icons and FontAwesome (The free version).

Comment: thank you Syed, but it seems that you didn't understand exactly my question

Comment: @arrmani88 Do elaborate then. I believe you need the icon to appear within the content. This does exactly that. You can include the icon component anywhere.

Comment: I already have my icons package, and also already know how to statically add an icon inside a text

Comment: Then what is it that you require?

Comment: If you want it to be literal text, you can use UTF-8 supported unicode glyphs such as `&#x2398;` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714969/is-there-a-unicode-character-for-copy-and-paste

Comment: For open in new tab, you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45806420/13349935 `&#x2197;`. Let me know if this is what you are looking for so that we can mark the question as duplicate.